# Change WooCommerce variation data "plugin"

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

While editing a variable product, you can go to the "variations" tab and edit the data for each variation (such as the SKU).

I want to edit this data programmatically.

The WC_Product_Variation class does not allow to set the value for those fields, just to get them.

Is there another way to set those fields programmatically?

Comment: Why would you want to modify the SKU? I'd like to understand what problem you are trying to solve.  It is possible to modify the SKU by using the method set_sku() method inherited from WC_Product

Comment: I am trying to change the Image of some(!) of the variations.

Comment: Your question doesn't mention anything about images.  Please update your question to reflect this.